# Android - Prevent TabLayout's children from clipping Tab contents

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tabs, android-tablayout, clip

The problem is simple. I have a TabLayout inside a CoordinatorLayout, and I dynamically set a CustomView for each Tab at runtime. The tabs have some animations and custom content that currently gets clipped at the Tab's edges.

I've set clipToPadding and clipChildren to `false` throughout all the view hierarchy with no success. Tabs are still getting clipped.

So the question is, how to avoid clipping tab's custom views inside a TabLayout?

Here's some code so you can see what I'm doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainTabbedActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    ... />
```

And then, a custom Tab looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/tab_pic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/something"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

The result is the ImageView being clipped when animating its position/bounds.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this was quick. I found the solution. It seems to me that Android creates an intermediate parent view between the TabLayout and the actual tab content.

So doing the following for each tab...:

```
ViewGroup realTabs = ((ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
    realTabs.setClipToPadding(false);
    realTabs.setClipChildren(false);

    if (realTabs.getChildAt(0) instanceof ViewGroup) { // <-- This is the intermediate parent ViewGroup
        ((ViewGroup)realTab0.getChildAt(0)).setClipToPadding(false);
        ((ViewGroup)realTab0.getChildAt(0)).setClipChildren(false);
    }
```

...will solve the problem.

Thanks